# Display node with specific revision

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to load a node using the revisioning module to display an unpublished piece of content, by passing a version ID to `node_load()`. We also use the i18n module which may or may not have an affect on what I am trying to achieve. We are looking to implement a "preview" of a page which may be sent out to departments that do not have a user account of any sort (We do not want to create a login for this). The preview page is requested with the version `&vid=12345` and a `&preview` URL parameter.

At the moment, if the specific revision is not published, the preview page will load the currently published content instead of the version we are passing to node_load().

I have tried to create a preview user with view unpublished permissions, but this does not work (still loads the published content).

Is it possible to prevent the fallback and load the specific revision?

UPDATE:
Thank you for the renewed interest. So we are using the "entity_translation module" and have extended this to include the preview functionality. This allows a page URL to be called with the node id and version id. These are both passed to node_load.
The node is then displayed via calls to `$output = _revisioning_view($node);` and finally `drupal_deliver_page($output);`

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more information about how your preview page works to answer the problem. There's nothing in the `node_load()` or its function dependencies that restrict loading by the user role. Without clarity on how this preview page works, you can't get to the core of what you're asking.

Comment: It would help if you could share a bit more of your code.  Particularly whatever menu item you are using (or altering) to create this preview function.  Likely you'll need to come up with a custom route and permissions to by-pass the security system since Drupal's default behavior will be to prevent this behaviors just like this (since it opens unpublished content to non-authenticated users).

Comment: Are you by any chance using workbench moderation module?

Comment: I've added more notes. @googletorp no, we're not using the workbench moderation module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this by custom method try below code to get published revision id.

```
$query = db_select('node_revision','nr');
$query->join('node','n','n.nid=nr.nid');
$query->fields('nr',array('vid','status','nid'));
$query->condition('nr.status',1,'=');
$query->condition('nr.nid',$nid,'=');
$result = $query->orderby('vid','DESC')->range(0,1)->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Pass $nid in condition, here you will get the latest published revision ID.

Then load node as

> entity_revision_load('node', $result->vid)

This will load particular revision id with content type.

Here you will get all node data related to that revision id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The node already loads correctly with `node_load(node_id, version_id)`. The last call that our preview template makes is to `drupal_deliver_page($output)` where `$output` is created via a call to `_revisioning_view($node)`.

Comment: Is it possibe to change your output call to node_load(node_id, version_id) or with the above answer?

Comment: So change `$output = _revisioning_view($node)` to `$output = entity_revision_load('node', $result->vid)`. It still loads the node, but the wrong revision. I am thinking that something after `drupal_deliver_page` is rolling back to the published revision rather than the one I am after.